# Cannot create .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Language: python 3.7.4

While I am trying to convert my python file into exe file with pyinstaller, it does not work well.

When I run the following command in the same directory as the python file is saved,

```
pyinstaller test.py --noconsole --onefile
```

the following error message appears in the console and get no ".exe" file.

```
PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc required by hook for module C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pydoc.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of C:\Users\hiro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pydoc.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.
```

1. I checked the "hook-pydoc.py" file but no description about the hook version.
2. I cannot find "__PyInstaller_hooks_0_pydoc" module

Anyone have some help for this problem?

Or, as the last phrase of the error message says,

```
You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.
```

Pyinstaller have some problem?

If more information needed, I will add. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred when your main file calls files on other directories.

For e.g :- test.py uses db.py in DB folder.

Try to execute command with '-D' flag.

```
pyinstaller -D --noconsole test.py
```

Comment: Thank you Yasohara, I got the same result after trying the code you suggested. As a test, I used very simple following code:
"print("Hello world")"
and got the same result.

Comment: Oh, did you resolve your error?

Comment: Not yet, now I still get the same errors.